# Preparing a string by concatenation and accessing its contents

Tags: python

I want to prepare a string name by `concatenating two other smaller strings` and then access its contents.

Eg:

```
teststring = "teststringlength"
len("test"+"string")
```

intent is to get the length of the string 'teststring' , ie the length of "teststringlength" = 15

Comment: `python` and `c`, really?

Comment: You should review your question

Comment: In C `strlen()` is the function.right?

Comment: @PHIfounder Well is it a `C` question or a `python` question?

Comment: @PHIfounder the function is right, but that is not the question. He wants to access the Variable by concatenating its name as a string argument. That is possible in PHP, but not in C, and I'm not sure about python. (I.e. he wants that "test" + "string" become the identifier `teststring` that represents the variable)

Comment: I want to form the word "teststring" and then use it.

Comment: yes, "test" + "string" becomes "teststring" ie len("teststring") = 10..But I want len(teststring) = 15

Comment: You can't do that in C, use your string contents to access a variable whose name matches the string.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr i think that is up to OP to decide.lol

Comment: I am trying to do this is python  Arthur.

Comment: Can you please share the method that you plan to use in Python

Comment: @MarceloCantos gave you the correct answer in python. However, do note that it isn't good practice to use `eval`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what this has to do with C, but in Python you can do this:

```
eval('len({}{})'.format('test', 'string'))
```

This isn't very safe, however. If a malicious user is able to supply an arbitrary string, they can run arbitrary Python code.

Another option is to use `locals()`:

```
locals()['test' + 'string']
```

There are some caveats to its use (see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) for more info; see also Gabe's comment below for a possible improvement).

Finally, the preferred solution is usually to use a single dictionary instead of multiple variables:

```
data = {'teststring': 'teststringlength'}

len(data['test' + 'string'])
```

Comment: Why use eval? `len('{}{}'.format('test', 'string'))` does the exact same thing...

Comment: @Haidro: No it doesn't. The OP's question is a little confusing, but their intent is to access the variable named by the concatenation and get the resulting string's length (*ie the length of "teststringlength" = 15*).

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing. Still, [eval is bad practice](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: Why use `eval`? Surely `globals` and `locals` would be sufficient, right? Maybe `len(locals.get('test' + 'string', globals().get('test' + 'string')))`

Comment: great, it works Marcelo Cantos, thanks so much

Comment: @Gabe The `locals` call shouldn't use `get`, `len(None)` is the wrong error to raise. Also, In Py3K you could do `collections.ChainMap(locals(), globals())['test' + string]`